# Uploading signed and obfuscated MacOS and iOS apps from Flutter in Xcode

Tags: flutter

How to upload obfuscated MacOS and iOS apps in flutter?

I have successfully built my application with the following command. But I want to use Xcode to open the archive -> product -> archive" method to build a signed and obfuscated app and upload it to the APPStore.

```
 - flutter build macos --obfuscate --release --split-debug-info=./message

 - flutter build ios --obfuscate --release --split-debug-info=./message
```